# Is it possible to have a notification on negative votes as well?

Tags: discussion

Usually whenever there is a comment or a answer/upvote we usually are notified each time that event is but I was wondering for negative votes too

Comment: Why be informed of bad news?

Comment: I mean sometimes there could be an edit that may have led to negative votes or some missing info left so if we could get noti on these then it would be beneficial

Comment: Related (MSE): [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements)

Comment: @Makoto Because down vote is usually a signal something is wrong and knowing that gives you a chance to improve sooner rather than later. For up vote you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Negative rep loss is the most frustrating bug in the rep notification system. If you throw a bounty on a question, no notification appears, and if you i.e. gave a 500 rep bounty, you'll need to gain 500 rep before it shows positive votes (unless you open the achievement inbox of course). Negative rep loss suppressing positive rep is another issue, but it not displaying loss is a part of that.

Comment: A possible workaround until this has been added is to not click on the rep notifications anymore, let the number stay there. When you'll notice changes on the displayed number (up and down) without the need to check the reputation table in your profile manually.

Comment: @HerMajestyQueenofARC Sound reasoning. But the pessimist in me believes it will lead to little more than more "why the downvote?" comments.

Comment: Yes it could lead to some issues but we could include these notif only on specific scenarios like for a negative vote as stackoverflow gives a info that we should post a comment so as to why negative vote this could be made as mandatory this would avoid having extra notification for negative votes. I mean this would avoid overhead of having an extra notification category.

Comment: Mandatory comments on votes? [That's not a novel idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin).

Comment: Ahh.. then we could though consider cases to set a seperate downvote category on the same. I mean thats also right we cant set notification for all downvotes as for a new user it might be difficult

Comment: You mean something like what's mentioned in the third bullet-point in the question I just linked?

Comment: Yeah somewhere around that a dropdown alike

Comment: @Gimby Who cares about "why the downvote" comments. You'll have those anyway. It is all about giving valuable feedback as soon as possible. Those who want to act on it (or learn what is it all about) will have greater chances in succeeding. Even if you have 1 rep and you get the downvote you should also get the notification for that downvote.

Comment: you can ask on upvote notification by having a rep cap for a day ... just to find out how an answer performes.

Comment: Didn't we just go through an experiment where they didn't show negative votes at all, or past the first one? Getting notifications about every downvote seems to be the opposite of that experiment, and seems highly unlikely to be explored, let alone implemented, in the "welcoming" environment currently en vogue....

Comment: Many of your suggestions regarding downvotes have been suggested, and shot down, before.  Let's turn it around; apply those same suggestions to upvotes.  Do they sound reasonable?  Almost certainly not.  Therefore, they don't belong on downvotes, either.

Comment: @Makoto Because it's a useful signal that you have an opportunity to improve.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Being notified of downvotes has been requested many times before and shot down each time because the company doesn't want people to have a bad time on their website, even it means improving the quality of the site (and the quality of the programmer receiving the useful signal...).

Comment: OK, just since I don't see it mentioned - you can probably write a userscript for this. The rep notifications *do* list the negative rep, it just doesn't show up as a popup the same way the positive rep does. You if you can filter out the rep loss from downvotes (since it's not very interesting), the rest of the rep losses comes from other people downvoting your questions or answers.

Comment: @TylerH:  Is it though?  Every time I've seen someone request this kind of feature, it was more to the intent of being able to argue their point about why their post was not worthy of downvoting as opposed to addressing the problem.  Even comments don't fix this since that's someone placing a big ol' target on their back - voluntarily! - for someone who's upset about a downvote.

Comment: @Makoto To be clear, I *don't* advocate for requiring comments for votes (up or down). I *do* however advocate for getting a -2 notification on the topbar when a post of mine is downvoted so that I can be made aware that there's something I should take a second, more critical look at (though I admit in almost all cases where I've been downvoted it's been revenge downvoting over the years).

Comment: @TylerH Even in the case of revenge downvoting it's potentially useful, so you can keep an eye out for serial downvoting cases that don't get caught by the automatic check.

Comment: monitoring downvotes has no positive effect.

Comment: Downvote notifications would be nothing more than a trolling opportunity.

Comment: Thats the reason i included only discussion tag with my question starting with "Is it possible..." i hope that clears out

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Don't pay it too much attention; he goes around poo-pooing on everything, sometimes [literally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znMDK.png) :-)

Comment: Sure @TylerH :)